# Extract images using xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to get information from this website https://www.leadhome.co.za/property/poortview-ah/roodepoort/lh-95810/magnificent-masterpiece-in-poortview- and I am having issues with getting all the images of the property; more specifically the URL

this is how the class looks like:

```
<div class="lazy-image listing-slider-carousel-item lazy-image-loaded">
   <div class="lazy-image-background" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/leadhome-listing-photos/025c90ab-9c87-47d5-b11c-1cfbce3f67f2-md.jpg&quot;);"></div>
</div>
```

What I have so far:

```
        for item in response.xpath('//div[@class="lazy-image-background"]/*[starts-with(@style,"background-image")]/@style').getall():
            yield {"image_link":item}
```

But unfortunately this is empty. Any tips on what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Please include all the code necessary to reproduce your results. Thanks.

Comment: This is a javascript based image loader. If you right click and hit view page source you will see the HTML as it is in the DOM before JS loads the images. The sliding images arent there. You could remedy this by using Splash.

Comment: @ThePyGuy Hey, thanks for the help! Do you perhaps have an example on how to do this?

Comment: follow the instructions and get the docker image for splash and then pip install scrapy_splash. Then follow the instructions to make SplashRequest to the URL and the images will load in a browser based on webkit. Its kind of a waste of time if you ask me to go to all that trouble for a few carousel images unless there is some reason you want to collect images loaded in via JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect **original html source** of this webpage (CTRL + U on google Chrome webbrowser, !!!not html code from Crhome developer tools /elements section)
 you will see 2 important things:

1. Images in tags like `<div class="lazy-image listing-slider-carousel-item lazy-image-loaded">` as well as other data don't exists inside these html tags.
2. All data stored inside `script` tag and inside `window.REDUX_INITIAL_STATE` javascript variable:
    
   [image: original html source]

In this case we can convert data from javascript variable into basic python `dict` format using python's built-in `json` module.
 The most complicated part of this task is to correctly fit content of that `script` tag into `json.loads` function. It should be strictly a text after `window.REDUX_INITIAL_STATE =` and before next javascript operation (in this case before the latest `;` symbol).
As result we will get this code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    script_tag = [script for script in response.css("script::text").extract() if "window.REDUX_INITIAL_STATE = {" in script]
    script_data = json.loads(script_tag[0].split("window.REDUX_INITIAL_STATE = ")[-1][:-1], encoding="utf-8")
```

As you can see on following debugger screenshot all data successfully converted:
[image: debugger_converted_data]
Images stored in `script_data['app']['listing']['listing']['entity']['lh-95810']['images']` as list of dictionaries:
[image: debugger_images]
`lh-95810` is entity id so in updated code this entity id will be separately selected in order to be able to use it in other pages:

```
def parse(self, response):
    script_tag = [script for script in response.css("script::text").extract() if "window.REDUX_INITIAL_STATE = {" in script]
    script_data = json.loads(script_tag[0].split("window.REDUX_INITIAL_STATE = ")[-1][:-1], encoding="utf-8")
    entity_key = [k for k in script_data['app']['listing']['listing']['entity'].keys()]
    images = [image["medium"] for image in script_data['app']['listing']['listing']['entity'][entity_key[0]]['images']]
```

This website uses javascript to render data on webpage. Hovewer any javascript formed content have it's *roots in original html code.
This approach uses only built-in `json` module and don't require css or Xpath selectors.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for explaining this and showing everything! It's very clear! Much appreciated! @Georgiy

Answer (score 0):

`/*` is to look for child element, try without it

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="lazy-image-background"][starts-with(@style,"background-image")]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xpath as:

```
//div[@class="lazy-image-background" and contains(@style, "background-image: url")]
```

This will get you all the **div** elements containing images with url on the page. Then you can add some code to extract image url from each element

Comment: This also gives me an empty list, maybe it's because these images are dynamically changing? @paras_47

Comment: Can you share the entire snippet that you have used? At least tell me how are you getting the response object in the snippet you shared.